# How to set path chrome driver in robot framework?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, path, robotframework, selenium-chromedriver

Now, I set path variable

```
path  : D:..;C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
Chrome : C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe
```

I can call open `Chrome` in command line.

But error when run in `RIDE`

> FAIL : WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to
>   start: crashed (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307647
>   (5a7d0541ebc58e69994a6fb2ed930f45261f3c29),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
>   x86)

Answer (score 12):

You need chromeDriver not Chrome.
Start by downloading the chrome driver.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Put it somewhere that your test can access (for example a bin folder relative to your tests).

Now you need to set the environment variable to point the chrome driver.

You can do it from outside the test (for example, as a global setting for your desktop), or from your test setup.

**From outside the test**

Just set the environment variable webdriver.chrome.driver to point the executable.

(Control Panel -> System -> Edit the system environment variables)

**From inside the test**

If you're using jython, you need to create a small java library to do that for you

```
public void setSystemProperty(String key, String value) {
    System.getProperties().setProperty(key,value);
}
```

And use it from your test

```
Prepare Selenium Driver
  Set System Property  webdriver.chrome.driver    ${EXECDIR}/chromedriver.exe
```

If you're using Python, you can use the OperatingSystem library

```
*** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem
Suite Setup  Setup chromedriver
*** Keywords ****
Setup chromedriver
  Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  ${EXECDIR}/chromedriver.exe
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Now I am trying to find out where this information is mentioned in official documentation of robot framework or selenium or seleniumlibrary or chromedriver but its not mentioned like how you have mentioned it. 

Either the documentation can be improved or I am not able to find the right information

Answer (score 4):

Download Chromedriver.exe from its official website and keep this .exe file in 'C:\Python27\Scripts' directory.Now mention this path as your environment variable eg. C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe Now Restart your computer and execute your test case.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to run your tests against a **specific browser version**, e.g. because your customers have a managed environment and all use the same browser version at a time, you can maintain the browser drivers in your source code repository and add the respective folder to the PATH during test execution.

My acceptance test folder 'atest' contains a 'bin' folder which contains the browser drivers:

```
atest
  bin
    chromedriver.exe
    geckodriver.exe
    ...
```

Now I can add it to the PATH variable during Suite Setup:

```
*** Settings ***
Library          OperatingSystem
Suite Setup      Include Browser Drivers


*** Keywords ***
Include Browser Drivers
    Append To Environment Variable    PATH    ${EXECDIR}/bin
```