# chromedriver does not find google chrome binary with robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I want to use robotframework with Google Chrome. Somehow the chromedriver does not find the Google Chrome binary:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

When I try to run my test with firefox, it works fine. I have search the net for some solutions, but I find only articles specifing the path to chromedriver, but not to the Google Chrome binary.

Heres what I have installed.

```
pybot --version
Robot Framework 3.0.4 (Python 3.5.4 on darwin)
```

Code to execute with pybot: google.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Hello World for robotframwork with headless chrome
Library  SeleniumLibrary
#Library  OperatingSystem
#Suite Setup  Setup chromedriver
### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537290/how-to-set-path-chrome-driver-in-robot-framework

#*** Keywords ****
#Setup chromedriver
   #Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
   #Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.binary  /Applications/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome

*** Test Cases ***
User shall call google and make a screenshot
    [Documentation]  First test
    [Tags]  Headless
    #Open Browser  https://google.com  ff
    Open Browser  https://google.com  gc
    #Open Browser  https://google.com  headlesschrome
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Close All Browsers
```

When I run this code I get the following:

```
pybot google.robot
==============================================================================
Google :: Hello World for robotframwork with headless chrome
==============================================================================
User shall call google and make a screenshot :: First test            | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Google :: Hello World for robotframwork with headless chrome          | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /Users/foo/workspace/robotframework/output.xml
Log:     /Users/foo/workspace/robotframework/log.html
Report:  /Users/foo/workspace/robotframework/report.html
```

Comment: Chrome at standard location? spaces in chrome path?

Comment: If you're at a command prompt and type `chrome` and press return, does chrome start up?

Comment: @BryanOakley what will it validate if chrome start up OR not after hitting command in chrome?

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/cannot-find-chrome-binary-with-selenium-in-python-for-older-versions-of-google-c

Comment: @DebanjanB the mentioned discussion does not describe how i use it in robotframework. Its nit clear to me where to integrate this hack.

Comment: @Dev - it will validate whether or not `chrome` is in your path. If it doesn't start up and instead throws an error, then it clearly isn't in your PATH.

Comment: Under OSX Chrome is located under ``/Applications/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome``. I added the directory to the path and added alias ``chrome`` / ``Chrome`` for ``Google Chrome``. On my shell Chrome opens when I use the alias commands, but it does not work for my pybot test. Still the same error-message. Its feels a little bit strange to add an alias, so that the Standard Chrome installation can be accessed... Does it matter that I use zsh as shell? Where can I get the information, which locations chromedriver checks for the ``Chrome`` location?

Comment: There used to be a bug in selenium, it couldn't process path with spaces. Don't know if it was fixed (you can google it). But if that's the case, providing chrome binary path should help. Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45503916/5318223

Comment: @jerik For information on _which locations chromedriver checks for the Chrome location_ check the discussions [In Selenium how does ChromeDriver executable finds Chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241845/in-selenium-how-does-chromedriver-executable-finds-chrome-browser) and [What is default location of ChromeDriver and for installing Chrome on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788257/what-is-default-location-of-chromedriver-and-for-installing-chrome-on-windows)

Comment: @DebanjanB perfect hint! I switched my Chrome location on the file system from ``/Applications/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`` to ``/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome``. That did the trick. Now it runs like desired. Based on the information of [In Selenium how does ChromeDriver executable finds Chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52259166/1933185) > [Chromedriver Requirements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @DebanjanB comment I found my solution.

The chromedriver searches for the Chrome Browser on OSX at

```
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

Chrome was installed on my OSX on:

```
/Applications/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

On my filesystem I renamed `Chrome.app` to `Google Chrome.app` and from that point on it worked. For any other OS, see the [Chromedriver Requirements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements)